# MVC ActionResult to use when returning html content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a some html fragment in memory that I need to render using RenderAction. For instance my action method looks something like this:

var html = "some html code

How do I make it render this html by using RenderAction, I don't want to create a view file because this is dynamic html. And I can't use any of the file results because this is not coming from a file. What other ways are there to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8):

Check out the `ContentViewResult`, or the shortcut `return Content(string html)`

Answer (score 0):

Immediately I can think of two options:

1) You can read this HTML string into a stream and then serve it back via `FileResult (stream, "text/html")`

2) You read this HTML string into a model property and output it through a view via `<%= Model.MyDynamicHtml %>`

The 1) is probably easier.